# How to TDD compound async process/tasks

Tags: actionscript-3, asynchronous, tdd, task

I want to TDD a compound async process/tasks but I don't know how to do it.

The process is like this:

```
UploadItem
  CreateItemOnServer
  UploadMedia
    IterateAndDo
      UploadFile
  UpdateLocalDB
```

CreateItemOnServer sends a command to the server and returns the item ID and some metadata. Then the UploadMedia uses the item ID and a list of media to iterate on that list and upload all media files. When it completes, the localDB is updated with the itemID and server metadata.

The UploadItem could be used like this:

```
var uploadItem:UploadItem = new UploadItem(itemToUpload);
uploadItem.addEventListener("onUpdate", onUpdate);
uploadItem.addEventListener("onError", onError);
uploadItem.addEventListener("onComplete", onComplete);
uploadItem.start();
```

- How can I know the CreateItemOnServer passed the right parameters to UploadMedia after it completes? What to mock/spy?
- Is this the right solution for a process like this?
- How can I know the onUpdate is sending updates from UploadFile file #1?
- How should I instantiate the UploadItem class?

It feels like forcing dependency injection, but maybe is correct.

```
new UploadItem(
    itemToUpload, 
    new CreateItemOnServer(), 
    new UploadMedia(
        new IterateAndDo(
            new UploadFile())), 
    new UpdateLocalDB()
);
```

Btw, I'm using ActionScript 3, FlexUnit and mockolate.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

Found how to test the setData() occurs before start() method:

```
var s:Sequence = new Sequence();
expect(uploadFileMock.setData(expectedData)).once().inSequence(s);
expect(uploadFileMock.start()).once().inSequence(s);
```

Comment: Yep, I was going to suggest you use dependency injection, but your last example is exactly that. Yes, it's not using a fancy injector framework, but it's still dependency injection. As for mocking, what I would ideally do is make my first test instantiate `UploadItem` and create mocks for all its dependencies. Then I would write separate tests for each class that I thought needed tests, and mock its dependencies. In this way its not an end-to-end test, but testing each class on its own for what it's designed to do. I would use automated UI testing for end-to-end functional tests.

Comment: Thanks Aaron.

Still need to know what tests should I create.

Comment: Well depends on what each class actually does. :) Test the `public` functions. Test against the primary use-cases you can think of. Add a test for any bug you run into that the existing test-cases did not detect.

Comment: Exactly, that's where I'm struggling.
`CreateItemOnServer` can succeed with metadata and can fail with a connection error or server error.
`UploadMedia` can succeed if all media have been uploaded and fail if one file can't be uploaded.
`UploadMedia` use the metadata from `CreateItemOnServer`, but only when the task start.

Comment: "UploadMedia use the metadata from CreateItemOnServer, but only when the task start."
Also `UploadItem` succeed if every task succeed and fail if one task fail.

I don't know how to test these cases.

Comment: Sounds like you defined some perfect test cases right there. Just mock the parts that it depends on to simulate that behavior, and verify the class reacts how it should. For example write a test for `UploadItem` that instantiates it, then uses a mock to simulate a succeeded upload and a failed upload, and assert that the `UploadItem` does its "upload failed" thing.

Comment: "Just mock the parts that it depends on to simulate that behavior, and verify the class reacts how it should."
As simple as it sounds. Thanks Aaron, I'll try it.